# Multiple Forms in MVC5

Tags: model-view-controller

I have an HTML Form devided into six sections. On each section the user clicks on the "Next Page" to move forwards. Or "Previous Page" to go back. At the end of the sixth section it has a "SAVE" button. I am assuming the data does not get saved until the very end.

I need to convert this into MVC application. Is there an easy way to handle this?

--**UPDATE** I am thinking something like this. Does this make any sense?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step1(Step1ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Session["Step1"] = model;
        return RedirectToAction("Step2");
    }

    // errors
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step2(Step2ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Session["Step2"] = model;
        return RedirectToAction("Step3");
    }

    // errors
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step3(Step3ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Session["Step3"] = model;
        return RedirectToAction("Step4");
    }

    // errors
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the data of each "section" in the session, when you call the "Next Page" method.